# Batch command paste several lines as input via Batch command

Tags: batch-file

I am currently writing a script that automatically decrypts a mail that a user pastes.

```
@echo off
REM create a textfile with the name of the mail
set /p textfileName=What would you like the mail to be named? 

REM create contents of the textdocument
@echo On the line below copy the contents of your mail that you received.
set /p textfileContents= 

REM write the contents to textfile
@echo %textfileContents% > %textfileName%.txt
@echo Your file has been created and is in the same directory as this batch file.
@echo It is named %textfilename%.txt

REM decrypting the textfile with gnupg
gpg --output %textfilename% --decrypt doc.gpg
```

My problem is that I want the user to be able to paste a multi line mail that is encrypted. Every time I try the script it only uses the first line that was pasted.

So if I paste:

```
hQIMA/G0CbVUEcdqAQ/9HwDqyk8xfQDdF/6iogMs7u3eW/6wMTGG8p3RawPKttbU
yduQF6lcF3diMHh2yBU93HAcU0xFL5mysm1AKQGYQSNaB5KheG2hSet80ViQePqy
```

It only uses:

```
hQIMA/G0CbVUEcdqAQ/9HwDqyk8xfQDdF/6iogMs7u3eW/6wMTGG8p3RawPKttbU
```

Is there a ways to paste several lines as an input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(
 SET /p line1=Please enter whatever
 SET /p line2=
)<con

ECHO -------------
ECHO %line1%
ECHO -------------
ECHO %line2%
```

Should do what you want. Windows may object to trying to paste more than one line from the clipboard and you'll probably need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> having pasted the data.

Comment: It does work somewhat thank you.
My problem is that the mail has different amount of lines depending on the length of the mail. With this solution I would have to add the exact amount lines in the batch script for the amount of lines of the mail right?

Comment: Yes. You could add extra lines, but you'd need to press Enter a number of times to complete the input